# How to pass data from one activity to another activity

Tags: java, android, android-activity

I'm creating an event app which contains a list of events in `recyclerview`.

The events `recyclerview` consists of the event name, image, date and time, heart image (example: heart shape like button on Instagram) which will change its color when the user clicks on the 'interested' button.

After clicking on any event its description appears and there are two buttons: 'interested' and 'going'. If the user clicks on 'interested' that heart color in the `recyclerview` will become yellow. The event will also get saved in another list where it will remain until that event is removed from the saved list.

So far I've completed saving that event in the saved list on clicking the 'interested' button. But I don't know how to change the heart color simultaneously and how to make it remain until the event is deleted from saved list.

**First Activity calling recyclerview adapter**

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


public class EventActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    //this is the JSON Data URL
    //make sure you are using the correct ip else it will not work
    private static final String URL_PRODUCTS = "https://www.test.magicalballoons.co.in/priyanka/event.php?";

    //a list to store all the products

    List<Product> productList;


    //the recyclerview
    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    ImageView homemenu;

    //SwipeRefreshLayout swiper;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_event);
        getSupportActionBar().hide();


        homemenu = findViewById(R.id.homemenu);

       // swiper = findViewById(R.id.swiper);



        //getting the recyclerview from xml
        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));



        //initializing the productlist
        productList = new ArrayList<>();

        homemenu.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(EventActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
            }
        });




        //this method will fetch and parse json
        //to display it in recyclerview
        loadProducts();
    }

    private void loadProducts() {

        /*
         * Creating a String Request
         * The request type is GET defined by first parameter
         * The URL is defined in the second parameter
         * Then we have a Response Listener and a Error Listener
         * In response listener we will get the JSON response as a String
         * */
        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, URL_PRODUCTS,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        try {
                            //converting the string to json array object
                            JSONArray array = new JSONArray(response);

                            //traversing through all the object
                            for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {

                                //getting product object from json array
                                JSONObject product = array.getJSONObject(i);

                                //adding the product to product list
                                productList.add(new Product(
                                        product.getString("id"),
                                        product.getString("name"),
                                        product.getString("date"),
                                        product.getString("location"),
                                        product.getString("image"),
                                        product.getString("details")
                                ));
                            }

                            //creating adapter object and setting it to recyclerview
                            RecyclerViewAdapter adapter = new   RecyclerViewAdapter(EventActivity.this, productList);
                            recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
                            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        Toast.makeText(EventActivity.this, error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    }
                });

        //adding our stringrequest to queue
        Volley.newRequestQueue(this).add(stringRequest);
    }




    public void onBackPressed() {

        Intent intent = new Intent(EventActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();

    }


}
```

**Recyclerview Adapter**

```
   import android.app.Activity;
    import android.app.Dialog;
    import android.app.TimePickerDialog;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.content.DialogInterface;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.graphics.Color;
    import android.graphics.drawable.ColorDrawable;
    import android.os.Handler;
    import android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout;
    import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
    import android.support.v7.widget.CardView;
    import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
    import android.view.LayoutInflater;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.EditText;
    import android.widget.ImageView;
    import android.widget.LinearLayout;
    import android.widget.ProgressBar;
    import android.widget.TextView;
    import android.widget.Toast;

    import com.android.volley.AuthFailureError;
    import com.android.volley.Request;
    import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
    import com.android.volley.Response;
    import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
    import com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonArrayRequest;
    import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest;
    import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;
    import com.bumptech.glide.Glide;
    import com.bumptech.glide.request.RequestOptions;
    import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
    import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;

    import org.json.JSONArray;
    import org.json.JSONException;
    import org.json.JSONObject;

    import java.text.BreakIterator;
    import java.util.HashMap;
    import java.util.List;
    import java.util.Map;
    import java.util.Random;

    import static com.example.priyankaregistration.URLs.URL_EVENT;

    /**
     * Created by Aws on 11/03/2018.
     */

    public class RecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerViewAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

        private RequestQueue requestQueue;
        private JsonArrayRequest request;

        private Context mContext;
        private List<Product> mData;
        RequestOptions option;
        TextView total;
        ImageView colorheart,heart;




       // Dialog myDailog;
        private Dialog myDialog;





        public RecyclerViewAdapter(Context mContext, List<Product> mData) {
            this.mContext = mContext;
            this.mData = mData;
            //this.swiper = swiper;



            option=new RequestOptions().fitCenter().placeholder(R.drawable.background).error(R.drawable.background);
        }

        @Override
        public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

            View view;
            LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_conferences, parent, false);
            final MyViewHolder viewHolder = new MyViewHolder(view);
            myDialog = new Dialog(mContext);
            colorheart = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.colorheart);
            heart = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.heart);



            total = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.count);
           StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, URLs.URL_COUNT,
                    new Response.Listener<String>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(String response) {
                            //progressDialog.dismiss();
                            try {

                                JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);

                               total.setText(jsonObject.getString("countid"));

                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();

                            }
                        }
                    },
                    new Response.ErrorListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                        }
                    }) {
                @Override
                protected Map<String, String> getParams()  {
                    Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
                    params.put("eventid", mData.get(viewHolder.getAdapterPosition()).getId());
                    return params;
                }
            };
            RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(mContext);
            requestQueue.add(stringRequest);






            viewHolder.view_container.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, Description.class);

                    intent.putExtra("eventname",mData.get(viewHolder.getAdapterPosition()).getName());
                    intent.putExtra("eventid",mData.get(viewHolder.getAdapterPosition()).getId());
                    intent.putExtra("eventdate",mData.get(viewHolder.getAdapterPosition()).getDate());
                    intent.putExtra("eventloc",mData.get(viewHolder.getAdapterPosition()).getLocation());
                    intent.putExtra("eventimg",mData.get(viewHolder.getAdapterPosition()).getImage());
                    intent.putExtra("details",mData.get(viewHolder.getAdapterPosition()).getDetails());

                    mContext.startActivity(intent);



                }
            });


                    return viewHolder;
        }







        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(final MyViewHolder holder, final int position) {
            holder.textViewName.setText(mData.get(position).getName());
            holder.textViewDate.setText("Date : " + mData.get(position).getDate());
            holder.textViewLocation.setText("Time : " + mData.get(position).getLocation());
            Glide.with(mContext).load(mData.get(position).getImage()).apply(option).into(holder.img_thumbnail);



        }





        @Override
        public int getItemCount() {
            return mData.size();
        }



        public static class MyViewHolder extends  RecyclerView.ViewHolder{


            TextView textViewName,textViewDate, textViewLocation,total;
            ImageView img_thumbnail;

            //LinearLayout view_container;
            CardView view_container;

            public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
                super(itemView);

                view_container = itemView.findViewById(R.id.container);

                textViewName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewName);
                textViewDate = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewDate);
                textViewLocation = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewLocation);

                total = itemView.findViewById(R.id.count);

                img_thumbnail=itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);

            }
        }



    }
```

**This is second activity**

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.text.method.ScrollingMovementMethod;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;


import com.android.volley.AuthFailureError;
import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;
import com.bumptech.glide.Glide;
import com.bumptech.glide.request.RequestOptions;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;


public class Description extends AppCompatActivity {

    TextView textViewName,textViewDate, textViewLocation, details;
    ImageView evimg,going,interest;
    RequestOptions option;
    ImageView homemenu;







    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.details);
        getSupportActionBar().hide();

        option=new RequestOptions().fitCenter().placeholder(R.drawable.background).error(R.drawable.background);

        textViewName = findViewById(R.id.textViewName);

        evimg = findViewById(R.id.evimg);
        details = findViewById(R.id.details);
        going = findViewById(R.id.going);
        interest = findViewById(R.id.interest);
        homemenu = findViewById(R.id.homemenu);



        textViewName.setText(getIntent().getStringExtra("eventname"));
        //textViewDate.setText(getIntent().getStringExtra("eventdate"));
        //textViewLocation.setText(getIntent().getStringExtra("eventloc"));
        details.setText(getIntent().getStringExtra("details"));
        details.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());


        Glide.with(this).load(getIntent().getStringExtra("eventimg")).apply(option).into(evimg);

        going.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, URLs.URL_EVENT+"?userid=" + SharedPrefManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).getUserId() + "&eventid="+ getIntent().getStringExtra("eventid"),
                        new Response.Listener<String>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onResponse(String response) {

                                try {
                                    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
                                    String message = jsonObject.getString("name");
                                    Intent intent = new Intent(Description.this,Ticket.class);

                                    intent.putExtra("code",message);
                                    intent.putExtra("eventimg",getIntent().getStringExtra("eventimg"));
                                    intent.putExtra("activity","NO");
                                   // intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
                                    jsonrequest();
                                    startActivity(intent);
                                    finish();

                                    //Toast.makeText(mContext,message,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


                                } catch (JSONException e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }

                            }
                        },
                        new Response.ErrorListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                            }
                        }) {
                    @Override
                    protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                        Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
                        //params.put("userid",SharedPrefManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).getUserId());
                        //params.put("eventid",getIntent().getStringExtra("eventid"));

                        return params;
                    }
                };

                RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());
                requestQueue.add(stringRequest);


            }
        });



        interest.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(final View v) {

                StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, URLs.URL_EVENTSAVED ,
                        new Response.Listener<String>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onResponse(String response) {

                                try {
                                    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
                                    //String message = jsonObject.getString("name")
                                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),jsonObject.getString("message"),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();



                                } catch (JSONException e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        new Response.ErrorListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            }
                        }) {
                    @Override
                    protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                        Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
                        params.put("userid",SharedPrefManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).getUserId());
                        params.put("eventid",getIntent().getStringExtra("eventid"));

                        return params;
                    }
                };

                RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());
                requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
            }
        });


        homemenu.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Description.this, MainActivity.class);
                intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
            }
        });


    }

    private void jsonrequest() {


        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, URLs.URL_EVENTDELETED,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        //progressDialog.dismiss();
                        try {
                            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),jsonObject.getString("Event removed from saved list"),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        //progressDialog.dismiss();
                    }
                }) {
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
                params.put("userid",SharedPrefManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).getUserId());
                params.put("eventid",getIntent().getStringExtra("eventid"));

                return params;
            }
        };
        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());
        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
    }


}
```

I'm having heart image in my recyclerview . And when i click on interest buttton in Description activity the heart image in recyclerview get change.

Comment: Why is your question in quote?

Comment: can you post what have done or what you looking for in image or proper format ?

Comment: I'll explain what i understand from your question and comment on below answer. You will open Second activity when user clicks an item in first activity. There is a button to perform favorite (or whatever) action.The favorite image in first activity must be highlighted when pressing back from 2nd activity. Is it correct?

Comment: Yes, That's what I want  @Pramod Moolekandathil

Comment: I'm confused... What do php and mysql have to do with your problem?

Comment: @PriyankaChavan Please check the answer below.  https://stackoverflow.com/a/56806933/4364890

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are saving the events in some model class, what you can do is when calling the `onBindViewHolder` method of your adapter, check if the event is marked as save. If it is, then you either need to change the heart image to another heart image which is yellow, or you can apply a tint on the heart image to make it yellow.

You can change drawable by using this code

```
heartImageView.setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.yellow_heart));
```

You can apply tint by using this code

```
heartImageView.setColorFilter(Color.argb(255, 255, 255, 0))
```

**EDIT (Based on comment)**

If the heart is in the first activity and the interested button is in the second activity what you need to do is to save the state of the event when you click on the interested button. Once you go back to the the first activity, you can check the state of the event and then update the image by using any of the above two methods.

**EDIT 2 (Based on new code shared)**

After you get the response from your Volley call, you should save the event id somewhere to keep track of which events you are interested in (this can be in either a model class or some global list). When you go back to your first activity (which contains the recyclerview), you need to check each event id with the stored event id list that you have and change the heart for each event that matches.

Comment: Actually, my heart image is there in the first activity and I had given id for that image,   and interested button is there in second activity so how can I fetch image id from first activity to second activity on interested button onclick listener?

Comment: Thanks, I'll try and let you know. @Bilal Naeem

Comment: Hey, I'm using volley to store my events in the saved list. I had pasted the code for an interest button click. how can I save the state of the event  here?

Answer (score 0):

You can apply `color` onclick event to heart button like following code :

```
your_image_id.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.yellow));
```

Comment: this will change color for all event and I want it to change for that event which is in the saved list.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with the help for `startActivityforresult`

**In Activity1, start Activity2 as:**

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, Activity2.class);
startActivityForResult(i, 1);
```

**In Activity2, use setResult for sending data back:**

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.putExtra("updatedArraylist", "arraylist")
setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);        
finish();
```

**And in Activity1, receive data with onActivityResult:**

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, 
Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == 1) {
        if(resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            String strArrayList = 
            data.getStringExtra("updatedArraylist");
            Gson gson = new Gson();
            Type youListType = new TypeToken<List<Model>>() {
            }.getType();
            List<Model> yourTypeList = gson.fromJson(strArrayList, 
            yourListType);
            ArrayList finalArraylist = new ArrayList<>(yourTypeList);
            yourArraylist.addAll(finalArraylist);    
            youtAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }     
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In **first activity**

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SecondActivity.class);
startActivityForResult(intent, 100);
```

From **second activity**, you have to execute the below code before the activity getting destroyed by finish() or back press (For this you can override onBackPressed of second activity and remove the super class call and call the below method).

```
private void exitWithResult(){
    Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
    returnIntent.putExtra("result", "Id of selected item");
    setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, returnIntent);
    finish();
}
```

Again in **first activity** you have to handle the result inside onActivityResult method.

```
@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == 100) {
            if(resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK){
                String result=data.getStringExtra("result");
                Log.e("DATA", "" + result);
            }
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_CANCELED) {
                //Write your code if there's no result
                Log.e("DATA", "No result");
            }
        }
    }
```

**Update**

You can use an interface as callback from adapter to activity. startActivityForResult canbe called inside the callback method of interface. You have to pass callback interface to adapter through adapter constructor along with data set.

declare this interface inside **adapter**

```
public interface AdapterCallback{

        void onAdapterSelected(int pos);

    }
```

And in **first activity** implement the interface like this.

```
MyAdapter.AdapterCallback callback = new MyAdapter.AdapterCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onAdapterSelected(int pos) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), 
            SecondActivity.class);
            startActivityForResult(intent, 100);
        }
    };
```

Then **set adapter like this**.

```
RecyclerView rv = findViewById(R.id.rv_list);
rv.setHasFixedSize(true);
rv.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext()));
MyAdapter adapter = new MyAdapter(callback);   //This is the only change
rv.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Changes in **adapter** below. (You should pass list data along with call back as you already does)

```
    private AdapterCallback callback;

        public MyAdapter(AdapterCallback callback) {
            this.callback = callback;
        }

        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder viewHolder, final int i) {
            viewHolder.mBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    callback.onAdapterSelected(i);
                }


   });
    }
```

Interface also come inside adapter. I am not repeating it here as i already mentioned at first

Comment: Hey , how can i write startActivityForResult(intent, 100); in adapter as mine is mContext.startActivity(intent) and when i wrote startActivtyforResult it's showing error

Comment: @PriyankaChavan I have updated the answer. It will work. Please check

Comment: I did startActivityForResult and exitWithResult() as you specified but I'm not getting how to write onActivityResult in an adapter. Actually, I'm not understanding where to write it because my adapter consists of JSON parsing using POST method using Volley. So where to write onActivityResult?

Comment: @PriyankaChavan onActivityResult you have to write in activity itself. Then you can make changes to the list data and notify it to the adapter by calling adapter.notifyDatasetChanged()

Comment: Read my last comment

Comment: Don't forget to accept the answer if it worked. Let me know if you have any doubt. Happy coding

Comment: Hey I'm so sorry but im not getting how to do, im new in android , i had pasted my code for recyclerview adapter and second activity too . Can you tell me how can i achieve solution for my code?

Comment: @PriyankaChavan Do exactly as i mentioned in the answer. You can'r call startActivityForResult from an adapter, thats why we are using an interface to call a method in first activity to start next one. Read the answer carefully and make changes in files i already mentioned.

Comment: I'm getting Attempt to invoke interface on a null object error.

Comment: @PriyankaChavan You have to pass the implementation of interface to adapter constructor while creating adapter. And inside the adapter, you have to bind this instance to a variable in adapter (this.callback = callback). If you missed this step, then it may be one of the reason for your null pointer error

Comment: It's showing all the heart image in yellow color instead of that one which is clicked and saved. Please help me with it through my above code.